# How to set up dynamic purchase pixel in Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, facebook

my website has products with different prices so I need to configure the facebook pixel to track the total of the purchase. I don't know how to make the code works in my functions.php. I used the code gave from facebook page, but the pixel is not firing:

fbq('track', 'Purchase', {currency: 'BRL', value: get_order_total(); ?>});

Comment: That's JavaScript? How are you including that in the page - inline in the template, rather than enqueuing I guess if you have PHP tags inline? When's it set to run - in a document ready handler? Does the order total get written into the script correctly? You have loaded the Facebook scripts first? What actually happens - do you get any console errors or network errors in your browser debug console?

Comment: I am using a child theme and all the custom code I put inside functions.php. As facebook suggests I put this code using the hook 'wp_head' in order to run it on the site's head. All the events are triggering but purchase is not.